# How can I make this button open a new navigation controller programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

How can I make this button open a new navigation controller? I want it to force open a new controller from the right.

I need to do this all programmatically not using the storyboard.

```
@objc func buttonAction(sender: UIButton!) {
    let loginDetailController = UIViewController()
    navigationController?.pushViewController(loginDetailController, animated: true)
    print("Button tapped")
}
```

Here is the code that makes the view controller I am editing pop up when a user is not logged in. This code is in the rootview controller.

```
func checkIfUserIsLoggedIn() {
    if Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid == nil {
        perform(#selector(handleLogout), with: nil,
                        afterDelay: 0)
    }else{
        let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
        Database.database().reference().child("users").child(uid!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snapshot) in

            if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
                self.navigationItem.title = dictionary["name"] as? String
                self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
                self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
                self.navigationController?.navigationBar.largeTitleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]



            }

            },withCancel: nil)

    }

}
override func didMove(toParentViewController parent: UIViewController?) {
    checkIfUserIsLoggedIn()
}

@objc func handleLogout() {

    do {
        try Auth.auth().signOut()
    } catch let logoutError {
        print(logoutError)
    }
    let loginController  = TwoLoginController()
    present(loginController, animated: true, completion:
    nil)
}
```

}

Here is where I added the dismiss of navigation controller.

```
func handleLogin() {
    guard let email = emailTextField.text, let password = passwordTextField.text else{
        print("invalid form")
        return
    }
    Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { (user, error) in

        if error != nil {
            print(error!)
            return
        }
        //logged in
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        self.navigationController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

**New Approach?**

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class TwoLoginController: UINavigationController {
```

Answer (score 1):

> With Storyboards

First create a new file that is a custom viewController class. For this example we will call it YourCustomViewController. Then ( go to your storyboard and add a new viewController to the storyboard. Select that ViewController and give it an ID and set its class. After that is done put the following code in your function :

```
let controller = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Your View's Identifier") as! YourCustomViewController
self.navigationController!.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
```

> Without Storyboards :

**In your AppDelegate**

```
// put the following code in your appDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions function
window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: HomeController(collectionViewLayout: layout))

UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.rgb(230, green: 32, blue: 31)

 // get rid of black bar underneath navbar
UINavigationBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)

application.statusBarStyle = .lightContent

let statusBarBackgroundView = UIView()
statusBarBackgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor.rgb(194, green: 31, blue: 31)

window?.addSubview(statusBarBackgroundView)
window?.addConstraintsWithFormat("H:|[v0]|", views: statusBarBackgroundView)
window?.addConstraintsWithFormat("V:|[v0(20)]", views: statusBarBackgroundView)
```

**In your Action to present the view**

```
// this code belongs in your button's action
let dummyViewController = UIViewController()
dummyViewController.view.backgroundColor = .white
dummyViewController.navigationItem.title = "TEST"
navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = .white
navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white]
navigationController?.pushViewController(dummyViewController, animated: true)
```

Comment: I'm  actually writing everything programmatically, so I don't have a storyboard

Comment: How can I get the same result programmatically?

Comment: I think it's great that you're going without storyboards. You should checkout [Let's Build That App](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCuP2vJ6kRutQBfRmdcI92mA) this guy is an incredible resource.

Comment: I really appreciate the help but when I tap the button nothing happens. Any thoughts on what it could be?

Comment: Do you have the `rootViewController` set to a `UINavigationController` in your `AppDelegate`?

Comment: Are you properly observing your button? Does it print `"Button Tapped`" ?

Comment: Yes it prints, but for some reason that’s it

Comment: Oh wait a second, my rootViewController is set to a different controller. This one is part of login menu that pops up when a user is not logged in or registered. I wanted there to be a button on this VC that directs to a nav controller.

Comment: Okay. So when you recognize that there is not a registered user and you segue to this view controller, what code do you do to do that? Would you add that detail to your question

Comment: Ok I've added it

Comment: Is `TwoLoginController` a `NavigationController`?

Comment: Okay I got it. I'm going to add a different answer.

Answer (score 0):

After a discussion and getting more of the picture. This is how you should programmatically present a `ViewController` inside of a new `NavigationController`

```
@objc func handleLogout() {

    do {
        try Auth.auth().signOut()
    } catch let logoutError {
        print(logoutError)
    }
    let loginController  = TwoLoginController()
    let navVC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: loginController)
    present(navVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Then to destroy the navigation controller at the end it should be something like this:

```
self.navigationController?.dismiss(animated: true) {
     // 
}
```

Do this when the log in is completed when you need to segue to the next view.

Comment: Ok now the loginController fails to dismiss after attempting to login in. I think this is because you set it as the root viewcontroller

Comment: That is the one you wanted embedded in a NavigationController right?

Comment: Yes the navigation controller needs to be part of the login controller and then dismiss once the login controller is dismissed

Comment: Not exactly. I edited the post so you can see where I added the navigation dismissal. It is still not dismissing

Comment: delete the first `dismiss`

Comment: Same issue persists

Comment: And you're calling that in the newly presented view controller that is nested inside the new navigation controller

Comment: Yes, it is in a newly presented view controller that is nested inside the new navigation controller, but it is still not dismissing.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I was experimenting with different solutions, what if we take a different approach and make the login controller a UINavigationController. Check the post to see what I mean

Comment: No it should work the other way. Maybe you should present the new controller you want instead of going back to the first Vc for it to transfer to the nest vc.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on that line of code and let me know if it hits it.

Comment: Hey Jake I elaborated and changed my question a little bit can you take a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51032090/why-does-this-not-open-a-navigation-controller-window/51033415#51033415